# Stability Parameter $\zeta$ definition

Tags: meteorology, turbulence

Let $L_{obu}$ denote the Obukhov length, $z$ denote the height of measurement and $h_c$ denote the canopy(obstacle) height.

I have seen two definitions of the stability parameter:

1. $\zeta = z/L_{obu}$
2. define zero-displacement height $z_d = \frac{2}{3}h_c$. Then

   $\zeta = (z-z_d)/L_{obu}$

**Questions**:

A. Which definition is correct? Can you provide some reference where this is discussed?

B. What are the typical values for $\zeta$?